# INSERT and SELECT in a single query. ADODB throws "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed"

Tags: sql-server, adodb

I have 2 queries, both work fine in SQL Studio:

Query 1:

```
SELECT [id],[fullname] FROM persons WHERE [id] IN (5802824683954111059,1615647673927737)
```

Query 2:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table_1') IS NOT NULL
TRUNCATE TABLE #temp_table_1
ELSE
CREATE TABLE #temp_table_1 ( [key] bigint primary key );
INSERT INTO #temp_table_1 ([key]) VALUES (5802824683954111059),(1615647673927737);
SELECT [id],[fullname] FROM persons WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [key] FROM #temp_table_1)
```

But when I execute these queries using ADODB.Recordset.Open() method, only the first query returns valid result.

For the second query Recordset.EOF property throws "Operation is not allowed when the object is closed" error.

What is wrong with the second query? Does ADODB support multiple statements in a query?

The sample code demonstrating the problem:

```
    conn = new ActiveXObject( 'ADODB.Connection' );
    conn.Open( 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;Server=mt;Database=test;Integrated Security=SSPI' );

    rs = new ActiveXObject( 'ADODB.Recordset' );

    //sqlQuery = "SELECT [id],[fullname] FROM persons WHERE [id] IN (5802824683954111059,1615647673927737)";

    sqlQuery = "IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table_1') IS NOT NULL\r\n\
TRUNCATE TABLE #temp_table_1\r\n\
ELSE\r\n\
CREATE TABLE #temp_table_1 ( [key] bigint primary key );\r\n\
INSERT INTO #temp_table_1 ([key]) VALUES (5802824683954111059),(1615647673927737);\r\n\
SELECT [id],[fullname] FROM persons WHERE [id] IN (SELECT [key] FROM #temp_table_1)";

    rs.Open( sqlQuery, conn );
    while ( ! rs.EOF )
    {
        alert( rs.Fields( 'fullname' ) );
        rs.MoveNext();
    }
```

Comment: Could it be persons.id has no such values?

Comment: Can you please add your ADODB script as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to your T-SQL batch or invoke the [`Recordset.NextResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/nextrecordset-method-ado) method after processing the results of the `SELECT` query.

[`SET NOCOUNT ON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-nocount-transact-sql) instructs SQL Server suppress `DONE_IN_PROC` TDS protocol messages (row counts), which classic ADO has the nasty habit of returning as closed empty recordsets with no columns. Failure to consume these with `NextResult` will prevent the entire T-SQL batch from running to completion.

It's a good practice to invoke `NextResult` until the method returns False as that will ensure the entire batch runs to completion regardless of the `SET NOCOUNT` session setting. Note that this technique also applies to other client APIs (ADO.NET, JDBC, etc), although the exact method to consume results differ as well as the symptoms (partial result sets, undetected exceptions).

Comment: "SET NOCOUNT ON" mysteriously helped. Thank you!